# Why was Peter Parker so excited to be an Avenger?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, spider-man-homecoming

In *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, Peter refused being an Avenger at the end of the movie, yet in *Avengers: Infinity War*, he acted excited when Iron Man told him he was now officially an Avenger.

Why would he be so excited to be an Avenger in *Infinity War* if he declined being an Avenger in *Spider-Man: Homecoming*?

Comment: Wasn't it Tony who refused Peter to join?

Comment: Nope, just rewatched the scene, it was definitely Peter who refused.

Comment: It's not that he doesn't want to be an Avenger, its just that he's a very sensible guy and realizes he should concentrate on school etc.  That doesn't take away from the fact that he's excited to be 'part of the team'.

Comment: I want to be an Avenger....

Comment: Some interesting pre-speculation: https://www.quora.com/Why-did-Spider-Man-decline-Tony-Starks-offer-to-join-the-Avengers

Comment: Honesty; kinda a silly question. But the part you're missing is why he declined.... Something about a "test"; he thought he was being played.

Comment: Wouldn't you be excited if you were chosen by world famous (probably in more than one world), superior superhero team known to earth, which you adore,admire so so so much... chose you to be a member of them? wouldn't ya? p.s:I'm batman

Comment: @BrettFromLA How about be a part of Revengers?

Answer (score 4):

There is no factual answer in the movie, there can only be speculation. The best answer I can give is that Peter declined to become an avenger because he wanted to focus on his community, but when the universe was at risk, he chose to step up. To be allowed to take that responsibility as one of the team by someone he admires is incredibly validating. To quote Peter just before Tony accepts him, "You cant be a friendly neighborhood Spiderman if there is no neighborhood".